# Framework and References

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I used to use the VS2010. And there exists an option:

"Project "X" -> Properties -> Common Properties -> Framework and References"
And then I can add a bunch of references and set a few properties: 
"Build Prop.. Project Reference.. etc"

In VS2015 I can't find this "properties path" or the properties in them. I also have googled and found nothing. It happens that I need to change some of that properties. Any suggestion?

Project description:

- addon (principal); DLL to run nodejs addon (c++ with node.h and v8.h) (dependes on all)
- g2pproj - static lib to convert phonemes and graphemes (c++)
- libjulius - static lib with julius speech recognizer options (c) (dependes on libsent)
- libsent - static lib with low level features (C)

Another libs:

- ws2_32.lib - win sockets
- portaudio.lib - [link](http://www.portaudio.com/)

The error is in portaudio (only one):

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __snwprintf

I already link and add all the additional dependencies.

In VS2010 I can compile this project  without problems, and not in 2015. I want to use 2015, because is new and has the thread features

Comment: What type of project? And did you have any extensions installed?

Comment: This is a property page for C++ projects.  It was changed in VS2012, previously it only applied to managed C++/CLI project, now it can also apply to native C++ projects.  Useful to tell the linker to link a library project.  But yes, the properties you are talking about are hidden, they don't apply to a native C++ project.

Comment: edited, with more information